# Wanted: API to get multilingual product information from UPC/EAN barcode for mobile app

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, barcode

there are several discussions here where people were looking for services that will return product information based on a product UPC or EAN barcode.

However, those discussed there are always English results, only. What I am looking for is a **multilingual service** that will return language-specific product names.

Also, the app I want to use it for is not a shopping app, just product info. I need a brief product name, some basic information and a photo if possible. A price comparison would be nice, but it is not really needed.

So far, I looked at Google's **Search API for Shopping**, but that one is restricted to 2,500 requests per day and there are no specific pricing information if you need to lift that quota. And this API is for mainly price comparisons.

Amazon's **Product Advertising API** looks nice, but their API terms and conditions forbid using these data in mobile apps. (Right?) Caching the data is forbidden, as well. (Surprisingly, there are a few apps out there that *must* be using Amazon's API somewhere, but maybe those are just under their radar. There are several blog articles by developers who had their apps shot down by Amazon for violationg their API rules.)

**searchupc** has been recommended a lot here on Stackoverflow, but it's not multilingual. And I really wonder how that site can not be a violation of said Amazon API rules. searchupc is actually a price comparison site in disguise and they often return Amazon's product photo urls. Also, they return shopping links that are obfuscated using their own domain, which is another violation of Amazon's rules. How can this be ok for Amazon? Am I missing something?

There are several similar sites to searchupc, sorry I won't list them all here. Most of them are English only, some return German product names. Except for Google and Amazon, I haven't found one that allows a query by desired language. Most of them appear to be run by hobbyists or SEOs, many appear abandoned and don't even work properly, some offer API access but often with upfront payment or unclear rules. It's quite confusing.

Comment: Have you heard that Google and MS have translation APIs?

Comment: Thanks, but my experiences with automated translation is that it's a source of hilarity if you don't edit it by hand. This will be worse for product names, where you need the official name (that may even differ for various regions, see Mitsubishi Pajero or Audi E-Tron). I've had automated translations of movie titles such as "Terminator 2" to "Endwiderstand Zwei" and "Aliens" to "Ausländer". Not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm representative of http://aerse.com. Aerse provides:

- API to access and multilingual. Right now it supports only English and Russian product information.
- product images
- mobile app [for Android](http://aerse.com/omni).
- It is absolutely free
- No restrictions on requests (not so many clients)

Comment: To downvoter, Should leave comment to improve his answer. He is new so guide him the right way to answer. Don't simple put downvote and leave.

Comment: Although I didn't downvote, I'd assume it's due to the self promotion.